# How to compare two list and get the differences from first list?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, collections

I am stucked in a situation where I am having two lists. What will be the correct way to compare the two and get the result in third list. But here is a small catch. See example below:

```
ListOld = {
    [Name=Amit, Class=V, Roll=3],
    [Name=Naveen, Class=V, Roll=3],
    [Name=Sammy, Class=V, Roll=3],
    [Name=Neil, Class=X, Roll=21],
    [Name=John, Class=VI, Roll=63]};

ListNew = {
    [Name=Amit, Class=VI, Roll=13],
    [Name=Naveen, Class=VII, Roll=3],
    [Name=Sammy, Class=V, Roll=3],
    [Name=Sanjay, Class=VIII, Roll=2]};

ResultantList = {
    [Name=Amit, Class=VI, Roll=13],
    [Name=Naveen, Class=VII, Roll=3],
    [Name=Sanjay, Class=VIII, Roll=2]};
```

In above example, ListNew has got 3 changes, that are  updates in Amit and Naveen , and Sanjay as a new member.

So In my query I need to compare both the list and want to pick either updated or added item in first list.

I tried, Except(), Intersect(), union(), with Equality Interfaces but no success. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by writing an `IEqualityComparer`

```
public class SomeClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeClass>
{
    public bool Equals(SomeClass x, SomeClass y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name && x.Class == y.Class && x.Roll == y.Roll;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SomeClass obj)
    {
        return (obj.Name + obj.Class).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now, the linq is simple

```
var result = ListNew.Except(ListOld , new SomeClassComparer()).ToList();
```

You can also do the same thing by overiding `ToString` and `GetHashcode` methods, but `IEqualityComparer` is good especially when you have no control over the class you use.

Comment: Thanks but the same I tried and it didn't worked. AFAIK Equality Comparing interfaces work only when we have similaritirs. But here inmy case. I need to figure out the diference and pick those one

Comment: @AmitRanjan I also tested it and it works. How about posting a small, compilable test case showing what you have tried So that we can talk about  the same code..